# ¿Cómo puedo generar un número aleatorio cada 5 segundos y escribirlo en mi página?

Tags: javascript

Mi problema es que se como generar un número aleatorio, pero, si lo quiero que se actualice cada 5 segundos, no lo escribe en la página, ¿Saben cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Incluyo mi código:

```
var genesis= new Array("En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra." , "Genesis 1:2 Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas estaban sobre la faz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la faz de las aguas.",  "Genesis 1:3 Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz; y fue la luz.",
//enrealidad el arreglo es mas que esto pero es para una idea basica 
var numerito
function generateRandom() {
let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
numerito =(num);
console.log(num);


}

setInterval(generate, 5000);
//generate();

document.write (genesis [numerito]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta función te puede ayudar

```
const randNum = () => Math.floor( Math.random() * 1000 );
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando y documentado

```js
// Primero obten el selector donde caerá el número
const cont = document.getElementById('cont');

// Esta función genera un número aleatorio
const randNum = () => Math.floor( Math.random() * 1000 );

// Cada 5 segundos cambia el valor
setInterval(function(){ 
  cont.innerHTML = '';
  cont.innerHTML = randNum();
  }, 
5000);
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta pero mi problema sigue estando en que, el tiempo que quiero que se cambie el valor del numero, es el delay que la pagina usa para generar el numero y cuando cargo la pagina no esta definido todavia el valor ¿ Como lo puedo Arreglar ?